# Live time stamp conditional formatting - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, conditional-formatting

I need to make a comparison between a cell with a "live" time stamp and another cell with a static time.  I am running a macro which updates the cell time every 60 seconds.

If the actual time is more than 40mins past the static time I would like to conditionally format a cell to change colour.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you having a problem comparing times?  40mins represents a difference of 40/1440, so subtract the times and compare the difference to that.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your static time (formatted as time) is in A3 
and your "live" time is in B3,
First note that B3-A3 will give you the difference of times.
Difference of time is the value of percentage of day.
So Lets say A3  is 11:18 AM and B3 = 12:00 Noon
B3-A3 = 0.031944, multiplied by 1440 (minutes in a day) gives you 46 min.

SO apply conditional formatting as follows

1. Select rule to say format based on a formula
2. =(B3-A3)*1440>40
3. Choose format
4. Applies to the cell you want like $b$3

Comment: "Difference of time is the value of percentage of day." Hm not really. When subtracting two datetime values in `Excel`, then the time difference is in **fractions** of a day. 1 day = 24 hours, 1 hour = 60 minutes, so 1 day = 24*60 = 1440 minutes, so 1 minute = 1/1440 days. So your description is not really good. But your calculation is right. +1

Comment: Btw.: Your calculation (46 min up to 12:00) is from 11:14 AM instead from 11:18 AM.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running a macro, you could use the '=now()' function in the cell containing the current time/date, then have another cell displaying the difference between the static time cell and the current time cell.

Then, if your cell containing the time difference is a1:

```
If Cells(1, 1) > 40 Then
    Range("A1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End If
```

Or whatever color you want in the flagged time difference cell.